# Reduce inside of an apply

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm not 100% if using `apply` + `functools.reduce` is the best approach for this problem, but I'm not sure exactly if multi-indices can be leveraged to accomplish this goal.

### Background

The data is a list of activities performed by accounts.

- `user_id` - the user's ID
- `activity` - the string that represents the activity
- `performed_at` - the timestamp when the activity was completed at

### The Goal

To calculate the time spent **between** 2 statuses. An account can look like this:

| user_id | activity | performed_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | activated | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | deactivated | 2020-01-02 |
| 1 | activated | 2020-01-03 |

In this example, the user was deactivated from January 1st to January 2nd, so the total "Time Deactivated" for this account would be 1 day.

#### Resulting Dataframe

Here's an example of the output I'm trying to achieve. The `time_spent_deactivated` column is just the addition of all deactivation periods on all accounts grouped by account.

| user_id | time_spent_deactivated |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 24 hours |
| 2 | 15 hours |
| 3 | 72 hours |

### My Attempt

I'm trying to leverage `.apply` with the `.groupby` on the `user_id`, but I'm stuck at the point of calculating the total time spent in the deactivated state:

```
    def calculate_deactivation_time(activities):
        # reduce the given dataframe here
        # this is totally ActiveRecord & JS inspired but it's the easiest way for me to describe how I expect to solve this
        return activities.reduce(sum, current_row):
           if current_row['activity'] == 'deactivated':
              # find next "activated" activity and compute the delta
              reactivated_row = activities.after(current_row).where(activity, '=', 'activated')
              return sum + (reactivated_row['performed_at'] - current_row['performed_at'])

    grouped = activities.groupby('user_id')
    grouped.apply(calculate_deactivation_time)
```

Is there a better approach to doing this? I tried to use `functools.reduce` to compute the total time spent deactivated, but it doesn't support dataframes out of the box.

Comment: I mean, `reduce` is rarely used in idiomatic Python, there's a reason it was tucked back into `functools`. I mean, you *can* use it. Or yo can just use a regular loop, which is typically considered more "pythonic".

Comment: As you can probably tell I'm not coming from the Python world, more Ruby/JS/PHP where all of those languages have a first class reduce.

What's the "pythonic" way to go about this calculation? Generating a list in the function with loops?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want, you haven't given an expected output, and I can't really decipher your pseudocode... you want another dataframe? Can you create a small example input with maybe 2 user-ids?

Comment: AFAIK, `reduce` is a simple `for` loop, and is usually slow in Python. Working with Pandas/Numpy usually means you can and should use vectorized functions that are much faster. In this case, you should be better off finding the pair `deactivated/activated` then pivot.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga good point, I'm adding example output

Comment: @QuangHoang do you have any advice on finding pairs? I think ultimately that's my blocker.

Comment: Your output doesnt really seem to make sense. Anyway  when doing the groupby on user id, you could adjust your apply function in which you add a temporary column 'performed_at_end' which is basically activities['performed_at'].shift(-1). Then just subtract row wise, followed by a dataframe filtering on deactivated, and sum. Then return.

Comment: @flow_me_over I realized I had a typo in the last row. That should make a little more sense. I like what you're thinking, but there are cases in the data when 1 user can be deactivated & reactivated multiple times. This means that a single shift wouldn't work. Or there are cases when the user is activated and was never deactivated so their `performed_at_end` would be 0 hours

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I have given it some more thought and I think this is what you are looking for.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

def myfunc(x):
    df = x
    # Shift columns activity_start and performed_at_start 
    df['performed_at_end'] = df['performed_at_start'].shift(-1)
    df['activity_end'] = df['activity_start'].shift(-1)

    # Make combinations of activity start-end
    df['activity_start_end'] = df['activity_start']+'-'+df['activity_end']

    # Take only those that start with deactivated, end with activated
    df = df[df['activity_start_end']=='deactivated-activated']

    # Drop all that don't have performed_at_end date (does not exist)
    df = df[~pd.isna(df['performed_at_end'])]

    # Compute time difference in days, then return sum of all delta's 
    df['delta'] = (df['performed_at_end']-df['performed_at_start'])/np.timedelta64(1,'D')

    return df['delta'].sum()

# Example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'UserId': [1]*4+[2]*2+[3]*1,
                   'activity_start': ['activated', 'deactivated', 'activated', 'deactivated', 'deactivated', 'activated', 'activated'],
                   'performed_at_start': [pd.Timestamp(2020,1,1), pd.Timestamp(2020,1,2), pd.Timestamp(2020,1,6), pd.Timestamp(2020,1,8),
                                         pd.Timestamp(2020,1,1), pd.Timestamp(2020,1,3), pd.Timestamp(2020,1,1)]})

# Show dataframe
print(df)
```

```
   UserId activity_start performed_at_start
0       1      activated         2020-01-01
1       1    deactivated         2020-01-02
2       1      activated         2020-01-06
3       1    deactivated         2020-01-08
4       2    deactivated         2020-01-01
5       2      activated         2020-01-03
6       3      activated         2020-01-01
```

```
# Compute result
res = (
        df.groupby(by='UserId')
          .apply(lambda x: myfunc(x)).reset_index(drop=False)
        )
res.columns = ['UserId', 'time_spent_deactivated']

# Show result
print(res)
```

```
   UserId  time_spent_deactivated
0       1                     4.0
1       2                     2.0
2       3                     0.0
```